# Filter "between" certain dates with dates stored as text values

Tags: reporting-services, filter, int, between

I have SSRS Report with a text field MonthYear, containing values like "September 2012", "October 2012", etc.

I need to do a "between" filter, for example September 2012 - February 2013.

However, it seems to be imposible to do this any easy way, because this fields are in text format. I think that I have to convert this field to an integer format and then filter, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this. I used Replace function for every month, matching them to 1, 2, 3 etc. And make the filter using this numbers, so it was like "between 1 and 4" But somehow this doens`t work correctly. When i choose "Between September 2012(1) and March 2012(3)" it shows me all data for all monthes. But it seems that "Between May 2012(5) and August 2012(8)" works correctly..